# How to create confirm box for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, forms, events

I got a foreach loop which display many forms like this :

```
<form action="cree-new-user.php"  method="post" class="formButtonForm">                                                      
    <input type="hidden" name="ent" value="<?php echo $corp->id;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit redform" value="delete" />
</form>
```

When i click on the Delete button it delete the objet in my database. 
I would like to create a popup box to confirm if i "really" want to delete it.

I coded this with Javascript :

```
function Validate(event) {

  var thereturn = confirm("Voulez vous vraiment effacer cette entreprise ?");
    if (event) {
      if (!thereturn) {
         event.preventDefault();
      }
     } else {
   return thereturn;
   }
}

window.onload = function () {                                                          
 document.getElementByName("deleteEntreprise").onclick = Validate;                
}
```

It should display a alert popup, but nothing pop... 
Do you guys have any clues ?

Comment: `getElementByName("deleteEntreprise")` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get the button correctly you should validate in the form on submit event.

```
<form action="cree-new-user.php"  method="post" class="formButtonForm" onSubmit="return Validate();">
```

if you return `false` in the function it won t submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, using `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`:

HTML:

```
<form action="cree-new-user.php"  method="post" class="formButtonForm" id="delete-form">                                                      
    <input type="hidden" name="ent" value="<?php echo $corp->id;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit redform" value="delete" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Validate(event) {
    var thereturn = confirm("Voulez vous vraiment effacer cette entreprise?");
    if (event) {
        if (!thereturn) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        return thereturn;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {                                                          
    document.getElementById('delete-form').onsubmit = Validate;                
};
```

**[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U7DCd/)**